# I am trying to create a basic API in Laravel but not able to save or delete any data through it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am a complete beginner for Laravel so I am not sure I am doing this right but have been struggling with this all day. Below is my code:

Controller:

```
<?php namespace virtualine\Http\Controllers;

use View;
use Form;
use Response;

use virtualine\Post;
use virtualine\Comment;


use virtualine\Http\Requests;
use virtualine\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // $post = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();

        $post = Post::get();
        return Response::json($post);

        //return View::make('posts.index')
        //  ->with('posts', $posts);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        // return View::make('posts.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        Post::create(array(
            'question' => Input::get('question')
        ));

        return Response::json(array('success' => true));
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $comments = Comment::GetComments($id)->get();

        return Response::json(['question' => $post->question, "comments" => $comments]);
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);

        return Response::json($post);
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Post::destroy($id);

        return Response::json(array('success' => true));
    }

}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostController',
    array('except' => array('index', 'store', 'destroy'))));
});

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

I am trying to use the above routes to store and delete records. I am able to view them but not store or delete anything. For api/posts/1/destroy (GET) I get:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/Library/WebServer/Documents/virtualine/virtualine/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

and for api/posts/store I get:

```
ErrorException in PostController.php line 69:
Trying to get property of non-object
in PostController.php line 69
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/Library/WebServer/Documents/virtualine/virtualine/app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php', '69', array('id' => 'store', 'post' => null, 'comments' => object(Collection))) in PostController.php line 69
at PostController->show('store')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(PostController), 'show'), array('posts' => 'store')) in Controller.php line 246
at Controller->callAction('show', array('posts' => 'store')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(PostController), object(Route), 'show') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 107
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 108
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(PostController), object(Route), object(Request), 'show') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'virtualine\Http\Controllers\PostController', 'show') in Route.php line 204
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 701
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 703
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/Library/WebServer/Documents/virtualine/virtualine/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send csrf token with your form data , for example if you have a blade file called add_question.blade.php contain the following form :

```
 <form action="{{action('PostController@index')}}" method="post" ><input type="text" name="question" ><input type="submit"></form>
```

just add the following field to it :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

so it should looks like :

```
     <form  action="{{action('PostController@index')}}" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" /><input type="text" name="question" ><input type="submit"></form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Opetmar. Now I am getting the following error: FatalErrorException in PostController.php line 52:
Class 'virtualine\Http\Controllers\Input' not found
in PostController.php line 52

Comment: at the top of your PostController add the following line :

use Input; 

// notice the first i in input is  a capital letter

Comment: Glad I've helped
@hilarl also for better understating about csrf and why it's important .. read :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm normally a front-end designer and just getting into backend coding.